# Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch in matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm executing the following code to get a matrix multiplication between the image and `w`.
Why do I get the  `Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch` error.

```
[e,f] = size(outImg);    
m = zeros(e,f);    
w = [1 2 4 8; 16 32 64 128; 256 512 1024 2048; 4096 8192 16384 32768];    
for i = 1:e-3    
    for j = 1:f-3    
        I = double(outImg((i:i+3),(j:j+3)));    
        m(i,j) = I * w;    
    end     
end
```

Comment: That's because `I` is a 4 x 4 matrix and `w` is also a 4 x 4 matrix.  You are trying to squeeze the multiplication of two 4 x 4 matrices... which is also a 4 x 4 matrix, into a single location in `m`.  There are not enough locations on the left side of your expression for the right side to go to.  What exactly are you trying to achieve here?  "*matrix multiplication between the image and `w`*" don't make any sense to me.

Comment: Helpful tip: Press ctrl+a to select all code in your editor window, then press ctrl+i to auto-indent your code. That will make it much easier to read.

Comment: Here i have to calculate the index value , where i have an image and i made 4x4 overlapping blocks of the image and then i made a array of 2ᵏ values(where 2ᵏ=0..2^16) and i have to encode the index as =∑〖2ᵏSͪ〗where S^h = Image 4x4 block

Comment: I'll write an answer, because now I know what you're truly after.  You didn't include this information in your original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is carrying on from my comment, and now understanding what you're truly after.  What you intended to do was perform an element-by-element multiplication of `I` and `w`, then **sum** all of the elements in the matrix.  What I mean by element-by-element is that the corresponding values in one matrix get multiplied by the corresponding positions in the other matrix and that's the ending result. As such, you simply have to change the `*` operator to `.*`, then do a summation on this entire matrix.  In other words, do this:

```
[e,f] = size(outImg);    
m = zeros(e,f);    
w = [1 2 4 8; 16 32 64 128; 256 512 1024 2048; 4096 8192 16384 32768];    
for i = 1:e-3    
    for j = 1:f-3    
        I = double(outImg((i:i+3),(j:j+3)));    
        m(i,j) = sum(sum(I .* w));    %// Change
    end     
end
```

Note the nested `sum` calls.  This is because when summing over a matrix, by default it sums over all of the rows for each column and produces a single row vector that contains this result.  If you want to sum every single value in the matrix, you must call `sum` one more time to sum over the row vector to compute the overall sum of the matrix.  This should now equate to a single value, and you shouldn't get the dimension mismatch error anymore.

Good luck!

Comment: I want to store the m(i,j) values in a 1D array of 2 rows. 1st row wd be the m(ij) counter and 2nd row w'd be m(ij) value for each iteration.How can i do that,? Please Help

Comment: I have made another question. want to convert 2D to 1D array like array(2,count).